# C string problem. Entering integer N and string, I want to print out character on Nth position. (If N>strlen(str))

Tags: c, string, integer, strlen

```
int N;
char str[64];
/*Entering integer N from interval [1,20]*/
do
{
    scanf("%d", &N);
}while(N<1 || N>20);

/*Entering string.*/    

fflush(stdin);
gets(str);

if(N<strlen(str))
{
    printf("%c", str[N-1]);
}

else if(N>strlen(str))
{
   /*missing code*/
}

return 0;
```

So in this case where N>strlen(str) program should just count characters from beginning. For example if N is 5 and string is "abc" ,program should count "abcab" and print 'b' at the end as character is on N-th(in this case 5th) position.

I would appreciate help if someone can help me with missing code.

Comment: show us your code, and where the problem is

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your tries help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and illustrate the problems your are encountering in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This link explains  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I am new to this site and it is very challenging for me to specify the problem since English is not my native language, but I will try to do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I will try to explain it!
if you have N and L (let say the length of the String).
Then the position of the character at the Nth place will be calculated by a formula 
like:
N = (N%L)-1; (subtracted one due to the array starts with 0)
This formula works like this:
Suppose the I have string "avlgh" and my N = 6, then at then after counting to 5 there will be a remainder that will be the index of the Character at the position you are looking for.

I hope this helps, and if don't others will do the better job at explaining this to you

Comment: Glad, I could help. My answer was wrong but I think you got my point

Answer (score 0):

```
/*missing code:*/ difference=N%strlen(str);

    if(difference==0)
    {
        printf("%c", str[difference]);
    }

    else printf("%c", str[difference-1]);
```

Basically this should work now.